# Canon iP90 drivers don't seem to work

Tags: 20.04, printing, canon

**Ubuntu 20.04.2, Any desktop**

Over the last couple months, whenever there's a new update to software, I go ahead and install it and usually afterwards something no longer works. A few weeks ago, my Canon Pixma MG2900 series multifunction printer stopped working. Nothing I've done to try to restore it has worked. When I print to it, it acts like the document with any type of extension just sits there, 'Pending'. I've repeatedly checked settings and nothing I've tried makes the document print. A couple weeks ago, it would print ONLY if it was a PDF, but even that has stopped working now. And YES, I have the latest CUPS installed...or at least I think I do. All my printers have 'State - Enabled'. All of them show 'Test Page' available when it's selected as the default printer.

But here's the strange thing with the Canon iP90 I recently attached to the computer...if I click on 'Test Page' it will output 13 blank pages. WTH? Every time, 13 blank pages is the test page? That can't be right.

Anyone have any idea how to stop this repeated failure of Canon printers just not printing after an upgrade? Someone should have some idea of why practically every update to the software (served by Ubuntu) breaks the printers!!??

HELP!!

**Update: 16Jun21** - Still wondering if there is a way to get this iP90 Canon printer to print in Ubuntu 20.04. Works fine in Win10.

In Ubuntu 20.04.2, Installed the CUPS and set it up, several times, and it always prints multiple blank pages with a tiny row of smudges along the top of the page. CUPS even shows the iP90 printer when I install it, so someone attempted to write a FOSS driver for it at one time, but that's all I know about it. Dunno who codes those drivers so can't contact anyone, or group.

**Edit: Feb. 2022** Gave up on the Gutenprint iP90 driver and tried Turboprint for the free eval month. Worked great, really liked everything about it except the $45 USD price with no support after 6 months. Really seems too much for a printer driver in my mind.
So then I tried the driver for iP110 again. Back when I'd tried it shortly after picking up the printer, it didn't work, recently, I found that it now works as a B&W printer driver for the iP90. The Test page below shows "Printer: Canon-iP90-iP110".

But unfortunately, the driver seems to smear the any color printing residing on the page. Here's a picture...note that the faint printing in the background is bleedtrough from the back side. The B&W printing is fine, but the color printing smears horizontally as you can see.

Any ideas of how to proceed? Is there any hope that Gutenprint would do something about this problem? Is there a way to color print from TERM?

Thanks.

[image: iP110 Color printing error shown...]

Comment: Still wondering if there is a way to get this iP90 Canon printer to print in Ubuntu 20.04. Works fine in Win10. Don't even need to download anything.

Comment: Update: 14Jul21 - STILL wondering if there's driver for the iP90 out there that works. The Gutenprint driver for Linux just prints a single line at the top of the page, too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try printing after uninstalling all of the previous drivers you've installed, because as it says here [Support|iP90|Drivers](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-inkjet-printer/ip-series/pixma-ip90?subtab=downloads-drivers) after selecting Linux 64:

> There is no driver for the OS Version you selected. The driver may be included in your OS or you may not need a driver.

wich means that the printer is very likely to work without any driver in need. I used to have a similar problem on my Ubuntu machine with a Canon G series but it actually ended up working without a driver.

Otherwise the (not so comfortable) solution of running Windows on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) on your Ubuntu machine is still a valid option, you can share a folder between the host machine and the guest one to exchange "to print" files as well as "scanned" files.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Last time I did, I couldn't find any driver for it generically...which precluded testing it. No printer listed in 'Printers' means I can't print to it. I'll try again though.

Meanwhile, all these months, I've been creating PDF files and dropping them on the Win11 desktop so I can print. It was heartening to find that the iP110 driver actually worked finally just recently, but disappointing to find that the color routine software is screwed up.

Sooooo close to a fully functional Canon printer in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been struggling with the iP90 too on both Mac and Linux, and was getting exactly the same results as you. Tipped off by your iP110 idea, but having had the same results as you when using that, I ended up trying the Gutenprint driver for the Bubblejet i70 (which is listed as “Canon i70” in my version of Gutenprint, 5.3.3) as I found it and the i80 both use similar cartridges to the iP90. And it worked perfectly for black and color prints! So maybe worth a try for you? Cheers!

Comment: I finally gave up trying to get the iP90 to work consistently so I bit the bullet and bought that TurboPrint software. And it's worked great. Has all the built in features I want including a global reset if I'm playing around and set something in the printer wrong. And now the 6 months has passed since I purchased it but I suspect it'll work for years. I really love this little iP90 BTW. I found it at a thrift store for $9 and wow it does such a good job and it's tiny!